How to repair a pitted table
I have a table upon which food was spilled and left for a long time, causing pitting in the timber.  The pits are up to 5mm deep.
I would like to repair this table.  I expect that it would be necessary to fill the pitting, sand it down and re-stain it.  Given the depth of the pitting and the size of the table, I don't expect that it would be practical to simply machine off the pitted timber and re-finish it.  Unfortunately, the manufacturer of the table has ceased business and is not available to answer questions about it.
The table was made from Australian timber of some kind.

What should I use to fill the pitting, and how can I match the varnish?

Whatever you decide to do, since this is a table, the bottom surface is not seen so test you solution(s) there.  As an added bonus, you may find the bottom surface was finished with the same material at the same time, except it won't have the same level of sun exposure.

@quill, the bottom surface wasn't finished at all.  Aside from the edges, it's raw wood.

Er, I'm not sure you're interpreting this correctly. I'm not aware of any food (even extreme stuff most people wouldn't eat LOL) that is even capable of damaging wood beyond staining. Australian hardwood species as well are often noted for being tough, like really tough. Are they maybe from some other cause, a boring insect of some kind maybe? Also, what's the white residue on the surface? It's confusing the picture of what's going on here.

Now any cause(s) aside, is flipping the top over and having the former underside become your new top side an option? Even if there are multiple screw holes it might be a viable alternative given you're already looking at doing some filling.

@Graphus I think that it was ice cream or yogurt, left for several years.  I wouldn't have though that it would cause this damage, but it did.  The white stuff is remains of the food that wasn't cleaned off, and animal hair.  As for the bottom of the table, it'd require just as much work as the top.

I'd give it a very good cleaning and then give us another picture of the issues.

"As for the bottom of the table, it'd require just as much work as the top" Are there approximately the same number of holes as the top? As you mention the underside is unfinished surely even if this is the case you more easily start from a blank slate in the refinishing. On the top you do really have to get down to bare wood, so you save the step of scraping/stripping or sanding off the existing finish.
